# How to duplicate multicast packets on several interfaces?

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking, multicast, ip-routing

I would like to send a stream from a Linux server to several Linux clients via a multicast address. The clients are directly connected to the server but on *different interfaces*: `bnep0` and `bnep1`. Besides, as far as I understand, my multicast packets are routed to my default gateway `eth0`.

Routing table hereafter:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bnep1
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bnep0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I suppose I need to create a dedicated routing rule, so that my multicast packets are sent not to `eth0`, but both to `bnep0` and `bnep1`. My question is: how could I do that? I tried using `ip route` and `iptables -t mangle ... TEE`, but I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to implement routing rules in order to duplicate packages on the two interfaces, but to *merge* the interfaces into one.

For this, you have to create and use a network bridge. The bridge shall have a unique IP addresses, whereas the "real" interfaces shan't, even if they shall be up.

```
# apt-get install bridge-utils
# ifconfig bnep0 up
# ifconfig bnep1 up
# brctl addbr br0
# brctl addif br0 bnep0
# brctl addif br0 bnep1
# ifconfig br0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```